# Occasional 403 when getting Facebook access token

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-access-token

I'm having an issue getting a Facebook API access token consistently. Sometimes it works, but most of the time I get a 403 - Forbidden.

```
string url = $"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={clientId}&client_secret={clientSecret}&grant_type=client_credentials";
var facebookResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
```

Frustratingly, when I use the actual values in the URL from Postman, everything's fine. It's only when I use this C# code does it periodically error out. I've verified that the URL is exactly the same as the one what works from Postman.

Also, I'm not requesting any permissions because I'm only using this to get posts from a public page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was our internal proxy all along. While I can access Facebook, my site's Application Pool can not.